# Raphaël.js animation resume() fails on set

Tags: javascript, html, animation, raphael, resume

I have this piece of code ([**on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7nGcR/1/))

```
var paper = new Raphael('holder', 400, 100);

var set = paper.set();

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var circle = paper.circle((i * 30) + 30, 20, 5);
    circle.attr({ fill: '#ff0' });
    circle.animate(Raphael.animation({ transform: 's2,2' }, 2000).repeat('Infinity'));

    set.push(circle);
}

set.hover(function() {
    set.pause();
}, function() {
    set.resume(); // <- things get nasty here
});​
```

---

Now when the mouse enters the set, `set.pause()` is called correctly and all animations stop.
But when leaving the hover area it doesn't resume the animation(s), instead I get following error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transform' of undefined

I have no idea why this happens; is anybody able to help?

Comment: I linked the uncompressed Räphâël.js for debugging: http://jsfiddle.net/7nGcR/23/ After hover out, it resumes playback, but dies just before looping again at raphael.js:line#2946 with `e.totalOrigin is undefined`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Safari/Firefox, after some time after hovering out, I received this error message (using the uncompressed source at https://raw.github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/master/raphael.js ):

```
`raphael.js`, line 2946: `e.totalOrigin is undefined`
```

The only place where `totalOrigin` is set is the `runAnimation` function:

```
line 3072: function runAnimation(anim, element, percent, status, totalOrigin, times) {
```

Your code calls first `elproto.pause()` (line 3352), then `elproto.resume()` (line 3361). `pause()` sets the `paused` property to true, `resume()` deletes this property. But `resume` also calls the `status()` method right after deleting the `paused` flag:

```
var e = animationElements[i];
if (eve("raphael.anim.resume." + this.id, this, e.anim) !== false) {
    delete e.paused;
    this.status(e.anim, e.status);
}
```

The strange, work-in-progress `elproto.status` method (line 3323) is only called by `elproto.setTime()` and `elproto.resume()`. This function constructs some complex return value, but no active code uses its return value, only the commented out lines starting at line 2980.

This function also calls the `runAnimation` function, if it has a `value` parameter:

```
 runAnimation(anim, this, -1, mmin(value, 1)     );
          totalOrigin should be passed here! ^^^
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't pass anything for `totalOrigin`, and this is the cause of the bug.

I tried adding a `totalOrigin` parameter based on line 3312:

```
 runAnimation(anim, this, -1, mmin(value, 1), this.attr());
```

While it seems to work, it goes buggy.

As a second attempt, I commented out the whole line:

```
 // runAnimation(anim, this, -1, mmin(value, 1));
```

Result: it works, but the timing is wrong, probably the animation start time should be updated somewhere.

http://jsfiddle.net/7nGcR/26/
https://raw.github.com/gist/3067995/1e82de48eeacf98697b572efdc74c11a9b1d9d03/gistfile1.js

Comment: Awesome; very good analysis! Thank you very much! That's a good point to start with, and if I don't get it to work, I will file a bug report.

Comment: Exactly, that's why it needs further research, feel free to do the investigation for the bounty :)

Answer (score 0):

in the `elproto.status` method, you need to replace (lines 5127-5128 in Raphael 2.1.4)

```
runAnimation(anim, this, -1, mmin(value, 1));
return this;
```

with

```
for (var i = 0; i < animationElements.length; i++) if (animationElements[i].el.id == this.id && (!anim || animationElements[i].anim == anim)) {
    e = animationElements[i];
    runAnimation(anim, this, -1, mmin(value, 1), e.totalOrigin, e.repeat);
    return this;
}
```